# Generate Ruby Classes from XSD

Tags: ruby, xsd, xml-serialization

Is there a way to generate Ruby classes (maybe even ActiveResource classes) from an XSD so that they contain a way to serialize the classes to xml valid for the initial XSD?

I know that soap4r has xsd2ruby but it appears that the generated ruby classes cannot be easily serialized to xml.

Comment: There is a way you can serialize activerecord class-objects to xml. But I don't think you are looking for something of that sort.

Answer (score 7):

Shameless self promotion (hope this is okay on stackoverflow) but I'm working on an open source project to do just [that](http://github.com/movitto/RXSD)

Its still a work in progress (feel free to send patches) but the ultimate goal is to convert XSD to/from Ruby classes (which it does now) and convert XML conforming to that XSD to/from instances of those classes.

Answer (score 7):

Though this was asked a while ago, I came across a solution and thought it might help folks in the future.

My need was similar.  I have a .xsd from a colleague and would like to generate a class file from it.  My hope is that I'll be able to easily marshall the object and pass it to his RESTful end-point, where his Java server will unmarshall the payload and dynamically build the object on his side with no additional effort.

The solution I found was to get the `soap4r` from https://github.com/rubyjedi/soap4r.  I made the two *.rb files in the bin directory executable and then ran:

```
bin/xsd2ruby.rb --xsd <source>.xsd --classdef <filename_prefix>
```

This generated a new file with each of the `xsd:complexType` implemented as a class.  All other complex type were also generated with the correct inheritance relationships and all `xsd:element` was defined as an instance variable and a class initializer also defined.

Running `xsd2ruby.rb` by itself yielded the options:

```
~/src/test/soap4r:bin/xsd2ruby.rb 
Usage: bin/xsd2ruby.rb --xsd xsd_location [options]
  xsd_location: filename or URL

Example:
  bin/xsd2ruby.rb --xsd myapp.xsd --classdef foo

Options:
  --xsd xsd_location
  --classdef [filenameprefix]
  --mapping_registry
  --mapper
  --module_path [Module::Path::Name]
  --force
  --quiet
```

For the sake of completeness, I extended my class with the following (this is a "Prospect" class):

```
class Prospect
  include Enumerable
  def each(&block)
    self.instance_variables.collect{|v| (v.gsub /@/, '').to_sym }.each(&block)
  end
end
```

This let me use it as the body of an `Net::HTTP::Post` request.

To the question of a free `to_xml`: I haven't found it.  The ruby Object comes with a `to_yaml` and `to_json` out of the box, but I've not found any simple conversion to XML.  So it came down to a roll my own "to_xml".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that this might work.

require 'xsd/mapping'
XSD::Mapping.obj2xml(xsdBasedObject)