# How to create Ruby classes from XSD?

Tags: ruby, xsd

I want to call a REST webservice and deserialize the results into Ruby classes. To make it possible, I need to generete these ruby classes from XSD.
How can I do that? I tested a tool called RXSD, but this has been discontinued and don't work with ruby 1.9.

Thanks.
Fabio

[Edit: may be same question as [Generate Ruby Classes from XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543709/generate-ruby-classes-from-xsd) ]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543709/generate-ruby-classes-from-xsd

Comment: Have you looked at savon? http://savonrb.com/#creating-model-objects

Comment: Savon is for SOAP webservices. Is that a SOAP webservice or just using XSD for defining the xml responses?

Comment: I'm going to use a REST service and I have only an XSD for defining my classes.

Comment: About soap4r, I have already tried it, but it is returning an error. I think it is discontinued.

Comment: I tried soap4r again, now using Ruby 1.8.7 and it worked fine!!! But it does not work with 1.9.3. It's not a problem until I need only to create the classes, but I could need to use other functions of soap4r in the future.